# How to import external javascript in a User Control?

Tags: 2010, web-part, javascript, user-controls

I have a code-behind User Control  (myUserControl.ascx and myUserControl.ascx.cs) that are in

```
ControlTemplates/MyFolder/
```

and, in the code of myUserControl.ascx I need to use some javascript functions that are in a file myJavascript.js that is in

```
ControlTemplates/MyFolder/_scripts/
```

and I'm trying to import using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="_scripts/myJavascript.js"></script>
```

but this way I get a 404 not found exception. How can import this javascript to use in the myUserControl.ascx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the [ScriptLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.aspx) control instead. It allows you to inject your JavaScript code into the page header, where they script-tags belong. It also allows you to avoid multiple imports of the same file.

Also, the recommended location for script files are in the /_layouts/ folder ({SharePoint Root}/TEMPLATES/LAYOUTS)

This is how to use the control:
In the .ascx:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="myjavascript.js" runat="server"/>
```

Or in the .ascx.cs file (in OnPreRender for instance):

```
ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "myjavascript.js", false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the scripts to the layouts folder. About, the ScriptLink part, the truth is I've read the link you post, but I don't understand what I have to do. It's a class I have to call from the myUserControl.ascx.cs? from myUserControl.ascx? How it works? Have you any example how use it? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with examples of both ways (acsx vs cs)